# How to remove spaces above and below a card inside a menu in vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'am new on VueJS/Vuetify

There is some transparent space above and below the card inside a menu element

[image]

There is the code:

```html
<!-- Menu with card-->
    <v-menu
      offset-overflow
      bottom
      left
      min-width="200"
      offset-y
      origin="top right"
      transition="scale-transition"
      v-model="menu"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      :nudge-width="200"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ attrs, on }">
        <v-btn class="ml-2" min-width="0" text v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
          <v-icon>mdi-airplane</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>

      <v-card shaped color="red">
        <v-list color="transparent">
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-avatar>
              <img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/john.jpg" alt="John" />
            </v-list-item-avatar>

            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle>Founder of Vuetify</v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>

          <v-btn text @click="menu = false"> Cancel </v-btn>
          <v-btn color="primary" text @click="menu = false"> Save </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-menu>
```

I omitted irrelevant code from the components.

I used the shaped prop in v-card and red color to better show the problem

Additionally I checked with vue tools the component so  **measures are 267 x 230.6**

[image]

And  **measures are 267 x 185.6**
[image]

Does anybody know what I can do to remove the space?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you applied an extra css to a `v-card` in another component without using the `scope` attribute? If you don't set your style block as scoped this changes gets applied in all your components.

Answer (score 2):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-73563245-v-menu-rounded-corners-erqlii?file=/src/components/Example.vue

I tried your code but I didn't get those paddings at top and bottom. Just some addtional spaces in top-left and bottom-right corners.

[image]

A quick fix for this is just apply the rounded helper classes to your v-menu like this: `content-class="rounded-br-xl rounded-tl-xl"`

[image]

I you want to add some space between the menu and the button just use the `nudge-top` props and set a negative value to it like: `nudge-top="-10"`

[image]